# I would like others to explain their opinion of spring-android-rest-template?

Tags: android, spring, request

I'm using "spring-android-rest-template" since a lot of time, but i want know, if there is something better. I tried to check for see the difference between few libraries, but i didn't find something really useful, i mean for comparison.

Do you have any ideas or some explanation to improve every request ?

Answer (score 0):

Better yet (IMO) is using [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) `RestTemplate` in conjunction with [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API) `@Rest` interface.

That way, you can simplify an API call even further from this: (example from Spring for Android homepage)

```
// The connection URL 
String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/" + 
    "services/search/web?v=1.0&q={query}";

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the String message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "Android");
```

to this:

```
@Rest(converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class},
      rootUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={query}")
String getResult(String query);

//usage
String foo = getResult("bar");
```